# Flutter: How to update final int value in model?

Tags: flutter, list, model

I have this model:

```
Class Model {
 Model({required this.title, required this.amount});

 final String title;
 final int amount;
}
```

User get to see this data and have an option to change the amount. When I try to change values of `amount` like this `list[index].amount = 3` I got "'*amount' can't be used as a setter because it's final. Try finding a different setter, or making 'amount' non-final*" message. How can I update value of `amount`?

Right now I'm using this workaround:

```
for (final model in list) {
 if (model.title == _title) {
  list[list.indexOf(model)] = Model(
   title: model.title,
   amount: _selectedAmount;
  );
 }
}
```

So, basically reassign it.

Comment: you can't change `final` value, you can remove `final` keyword . if you want to create a model class its better to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/freezed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `copyWith` method to create new instance with updated value

```dart
class Model {
 const  Model({
    required this.title,
    required this.amount,
  });

  final String title;
  final int amount;

  Model copyWith({
    String? title,
    int? amount,
  }) {
    return Model(
      title: title ?? this.title,
      amount: amount ?? this.amount,
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can pass the filed you like to update like  `model.copyWith(amount: _selectedAmount);`

Comment: I see, so to update I have to create this method. And it will update value of needed Model in List<Model>?

Comment: Yes, I won't prefer removing final keyword, you can find many copyWith method on flutter classes.

Answer (score 2):

Final value can not be changed. remove the final keyword from the statement to make it changeable.
The final keyword is used to hardcode the values of the variable and it cannot be altered in future, neither any kind of operations performed on these variables can alter its value (state)

Comment: Removing final causes this lint `This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final:` Is it ok?

Comment: yeah it is okay. where are you getting this lint?